# MySQL populate column with calculated average from data of other column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: one is a name and the other is ratings connected by a nameID. I would like to find the average of the ratings from the data in the ratings table and populate that result to the corresponding venue on the venue table. I am not sure how to proceed. Any pointers on how to do this with MySQL?

Comment: You can start by showing us your exact table structure, ideally with data.

Comment: Is there any reason for storing this data? How do you plan to keep the calculated averages updated? Triggers?

Comment: Table 1: Venue | Address | AvgRating Table 2: Review | Rating | VenueId. The review table has review data on the venue. I'm trying to decide how and where to add the avgRating of the venue. The reason to store the data is to be able to search for the cumulative average. For data, this is similar to reviews of a restaurant and wanting to show the average of all the reviews.

Comment: As @shadow mentioned, you face a problem with how to keep your averages (which are aggregates) updated as the table grows.  Would you be happy with just a query to obtain averages for a snapshot of your tables?

Comment: I do want the averages to continually update as more review data is input. At what size of database does the snapshot start to be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

This should work but like others said it might be a better idea to take the average from the rating table, instead of updating the venue table with triggers. So this creates a procedure to update the avg rating of the venue which gets called from the two triggers for insert and update on rating table.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE updateVenueRating(IN venue_id INT)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

update venue AS v
SET v.avgrating = 
(select avg(rating)
from ratingtable
where ratingtable.venueid = v.id 
)
where v.id = venue_id;

END//

CREATE TRIGGER venue_insert_trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON ratingtable
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL updateVenueRating(NEW.VenueId);
END//

CREATE TRIGGER venue_update_trigger
    AFTER UPDATE ON ratingtable
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL updateVenueRating(NEW.VenueId);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```